# How to curl in Python with header, data?

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying replace the following curl command by a Python script:

```sh
curl --request POST \
 --url https://xx.com/login \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
"email": "user@domain.com",
"password": "PASSWORD"
}'
```

Script that I tried:

```
import urllib.request
import json

body = {"email": "xxx@xx.com","password": "xxx"}
myurl = "https://xx.com/login"

req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

When I tried to run this script, it doesn't return me anything and show processed completed. Is my code logic correct? Or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: What is `print(response.status)`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM It showed success, but how can I print token instead of `success` ?

Comment: Try to read the response body `response.read()`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM ahh i see, now it able to show me the token and other values. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP and HTTPS URLs, [`urllib.request.urlopen` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) returns a [`http.client.HTTPResponse` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects). It has different attributes and methods you can use,
For example,

`HTTPResponse.read([amt])` - Reads and returns the response body, or up to the next amt bytes.

`HTTPResponse.getheaders()` - Return a list of (header, value) tuples.

`HTTPResponse.status` - Status code returned by server.

So in your case you could do check the status using `status` attribute . If it's successful read the response body using `read` method.

```
status_code = response.status
if status_code == 200: # request succeeded
    response_body = response.read() # This will be byte object
    response_body_as_string = response_body.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can i use urllib as GET request? Does it the same if i use `req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)` ?

Comment: @terry5546 [urllib.request.Request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) also accept an argument called `method` which lets you to specify the method. If you don't specify anything the default value is `GET`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply just use `requests`:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{\n"email": "user@domain.com",\n"password": "PASSWORD"\n}'

response = requests.post('https://xx.com/login', headers=headers, data=data)
```